# How to add twitter card to angularjs website?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter

My website is built with angularjs. I am going to add social media sharing links to each posts in the blog. How can I add the meta tags for each blog page, so that when the user tweets a post url the title, description and image of the post appears in their tweet?

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: I am not sure where to start from. I am not sure whether the following method works. The page title and images comes from the database. So will it work if I add the scope variables holding those contents to the meta tags?

Comment: Start with the [Twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public)

Answer (score 1):

I am using : https://github.com/AvraamMavridis/angular-metatags library and here is my example :

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute','metatags']);
```

Inject the MetaTagsProvider in the config and define your meta tags

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider','MetaTagsProvider', function($routeProvider, MetaTagsProvider) {
        MetaTagsProvider
          .when('/', {
            title: 'Great',
            description: 'Cool',
            twitter_card: 'summary_large_image'
            twitter_title: 'My title',
            twitter_site: 'My site name' ,
            twitter_domain: 'example.com'
            twitter_url: 'http://example.com/example-page.html',
            twitter_desc: 'Cool website',
            twitter_image: 'http://example.com/images/an_image.jpg'
          })
          .........
    }]);
```

then in your rootScope define the metatags :

```
$rootScope.metatags =  { 
  title: "A Great article on angularJS",
  description:"",
  twitter_title: "A Great article on angularJS", 
  twitter_desc: "A Great article on angularJS which describe etc etc blah blah", 
  twitter_site: "example.com",
  twitter_image: "http://example.com/images/an_image.jpg"
}
```

then initialize the provider in your application like :

```
myApp.run(function(MetaTags){
    MetaTags.initialize();
});
```

the in index.html inside head section add the following lines :

```
<meta ng-if="metatags.twitter_card !=''" property="twitter:card" content="{{metatags.twitter_card}}">
    <meta ng-if="metatags.twitter_site !=''" property="twitter:site" content="{{metatags.twitter_site}}">
    <meta ng-if="metatags.twitter_domain !=''" name="twitter:domain" content="{{metatags.twitter_domain}}">
    <meta ng-if="metatags.twitter_title !=''" property="twitter:title" content="{{metatags.twitter_title}}">
    <meta ng-if="metatags.twitter_desc !=''" property="twitter:description" content="{{metatags.twitter_desc}}">
    <meta ng-if="metatags.twitter_image !=''" property="twitter:image" content="{{metatags.twitter_image}}">
```

and this will work, but do remember this will work only if you use services like prerender.io or prerender with redis nice tutorial at (because twitter bot will need prerendered HTML of your page) : http://www.doz.com/search-engine/angularjs-index-seo

rest if you want extra twitter stuff like player etc, then read [twitter developer docs](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/types).